# I can't show EMAs crossings

Tags: python, pine-script, trading

I have a script on TradingView. This script shows five EMAs. I want it to mark the crosses between the EMAs. I tried this with some lines from another code, but it doesn't works. My code is below:

```
EMA8 = input(8, minval=1, title="EMA8"),
EMA21 = input(21, minval=1, title="EMA21")
EMA55 = input(55, minval=1, title="EMA55"),
EMA233 = input(233, minval=1, title="EMA233"),
EMA377 = input(377, minval=1, title="EMA377"),

plot(ema(close, EMA8), color=white, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA21), color=red, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA55), color=blue, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA233), color=purple, linewidth=2)
plot(ema(close, EMA377), color=green, linewidth=2)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA21 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 4)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color = (EMA21 - EMA8 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA21, EMA55) ? EMA55 : na, color = (EMA55 - EMA21 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA55, EMA233) ? EMA233 : na, color = (EMA233 - EMA55 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(EMA233, EMA377) ? EMA377 : na, color = (EMA377 - EMA233 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
```

This is the original code where I extracted the last two lines:

```
plot(wt1, color=green)
plot(wt2, color=red)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = black , style = circles, linewidth = 3)
plot(cross(wt1, wt2) ? wt2 : na, color = (wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? red : lime) , style = circles, linewidth = 2)
```

The sintax of the codes are right, but it still doesn't show the crosses between the EMAs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working because you're using the input lengths in the `cross()` comparisons and not the EMAs themselves. So `cross(EMA8, EMA21)` is the equivalent of `cross(8, 21)`. 8 and 21 are never going to cross, so never meet your condition. You need to assign a variable to each EMA and compare the actual EMAs instead eg

```
EMA8len = input(8, minval=1, title="EMA8")
EMA21len = input(21, minval=1, title="EMA21")

EMA8 = ema(close, EMA8len)
EMA21 = ema(close, EMA21len)

plot(EMA8, color = white, linewidth = 2)
plot(EMA21, color = red, linewidth = 2)
plot(cross(EMA8, EMA21) ? EMA21 : na, color = black, style = circles, linewidth = 4)
```